# find and differentiate words in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, ecmascript-6, filter

I have a problem with javascript. Basically I have a text:

```
const text = 'Hello Teddy Bear, enjoy your life'.
```

And I have an array with two elements

```
const array = ['Teddy', 'Teddy Bear'];
```

I need to filter from this array only 'Teddy Bear'.

I'm trying to use the 'includes' from javascript. But he can't find the difference because there is 'Teddy' in the text too..

Does anyone know how I can solve? Thanks

Comment: Use .replace() function

Comment: humm.. could you give some example?

Comment: If it is about the longest possible matching (sub)string, it is actually very easy. 1st) `sort` the array descending by each of its string-items `length` property. 2nd) iterate the array ... for each string item try whether it is included within the given text. Stop iterating with the first matching string-item. No need of regex at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is about the longest possible matching (sub)string, thus the *most specific* one, the task actually can be solved pretty easy.

1. `sort` the array descending by each of its string-item's `length` property.
2. Iterate the array ... for each string item, try whether it is included within the given text.
3. Stop iterating with the first matching string-item.

No need of regex at all.

```js
function getMostSpecificMatch(text, matchList) {
  let match;

  matchList
    .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
    .some(str => {
      const doesMatch = text.includes(str);
      if (doesMatch) {

        match = str;
      }
      return doesMatch;
    });

  return match;
}

const sampleText = 'Hello Teddy Bear, enjoy your life';
const sampleList = ['Teddy', 'Teddy Bear'];

console.log(
  'randomly ordered list of possible matches ...',
  sampleList
);
console.log(
  "possible matches in descending order of each item's length ...",
  sampleList.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
);
console.log({ sampleText });

console.log(
  'most specific match ...',
  getMostSpecificMatch(sampleText, sampleList)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @ThadeuMunhózCesário ... are there any questions left regarding the above approach?

Comment: No Peter, thanks so much for helping! I will take advantage of your code and also make some adaptations for my case.

Thank you very much!